# BlazeDS rejected connection from some IP address

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat6, blazeds

I'm using the BlazeDS binary version with Apache tomcat 6.0. And it seems there's a developer mode active and it only allows 3 IPs to connect to the application (Server).

This is what the log says:

```
[BlazeDS]MessageBroker '__default__' rejected connection from address 'xxx.xxx.xx.x';       Developer mode addresses already in use: xxx.x.xxx.xx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

(IP addresses are masked with 'x' for privacy)

I have not added any special configuration to make developer mode active. I couldn't find any resources related to this scenario either. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Livecycle DataServices without having a serial number you'll have this limitation. However that's not the case for BlazeDS. So please check again, I think you have installed LCDS instead of BlazeDS.

Comment: Hi Cornel, Thank you for the response. I'm 100% sure this is BlazeDS. But the application was running in a LCDS trial before. I just copied the app from LCDS webapps to BlaseDS webapps. Can there be any configuration remaining from the previous LCDS?

Comment: LCDS and BlazeDS are in fact just a bunch of jars.. you should replace all the LCDS jar file from your webapp with the ones from BlazeDS (the flex*.jar files). It's not only a configuration issue, the code for checking the license only exists in LCDS.